# Probit regression with data augmentation in stan

Tags: r, stan

I am attempting to do a probit model with data augmentation using stan. This is where we have outcomes `y` either 0/1 that tell us the sign of the latent variable `ystar`. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to add information in the `model` section about `y`. Any thoughts?

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N; // number of obs
  int<lower=0> K; // number of predictors
  int<lower=0,upper=1> y[N]; // outcomes
  matrix[N, K] x; // predictor variables
}
parameters {
  vector[K] beta; // beta coefficients
  vector[N] ystar; // latent variable
}
model {
  vector[N] mu; 
  beta ~ normal(0, 100);
  mu <- x*beta;
  ystar ~ normal(mu, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do

`data {
  int<lower=0> N; // number of obs
  int<lower=0> K; // number of predictors
  vector<lower=-1,upper=1> sign; // y = 0 -> -1, y = 1 -> 1
  matrix[N, K] x; // predictor variables
}
parameters {
  vector[K] beta; // beta coefficients
  vector<lower=0>[N] abs_ystar; // latent variable
}
model {
  beta ~ normal(0, 100);
  // ignore the warning about a Jacobian from the parser
  sign .* abs_ystar ~ normal(x * beta, 1);
}`

That said, there is no reason to do data augmentation in Stan for a binary probit model, unless some of the outcomes were missing or something. It is more straightforward (and reduces the parameter space to K instead of K + N) to do

`data {
  int<lower=0> N; // number of obs
  int<lower=0> K; // number of predictors
  int<lower=0,upper=1> y[N]; // outcomes
  matrix[N, K] x; // predictor variables
}
parameters {
  vector[K] beta; // beta coefficients
}
model {
  vector[N] mu; 
  beta ~ normal(0, 100);
  mu <- x*beta;
  for (n in 1:N) mu[n] <- Phi(mu[n]);
  y ~ bernoulli(mu);
}`

If you really care about the latent utility, you could generate it via rejection sampling in the `generated quantities` block, like this

`generated quantities {
  vector[N] ystar;
  {
    vector[N] mu;
    mu <- x * beta;
    for (n in 1:N) {
      real draw;
      draw <- not_a_number();
      if (sign[n] == 1) while(!(draw > 0)) draw <- normal_rng(mu[n], 1);
      else while(!(draw < 0)) draw <- normal_rng(mu[n], 1);
      ystar[n] <- draw;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. It makes sense to reduce the parameter space if possible. I am interested in the latent utility, though. How would I calculate that using `generated quantities`? It seems like I'd have to generate a model similar to the first one you suggest, at which point I'm back to sampling K+N. Is that the case, or is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: The things you define in `generated quantities` do not affect the sampling, so it is just a minor storage issue.

Comment: @BenGoodrich Hi Ben, what do `draw <- not_a_number();` and the while loop mean in generated quantities? Can't we simply use `ystar[n]<-normal_rng(mu[n],1)`?